# View is in the last position of parent, but still being blocked

Tags: android, view, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet, view-hierarchy

#### What I want to do

In a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, I want to inflate a view that always stick at the bottom of the screen, no matter what [state (collapsed / expanded)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html) the `BottomSheetBehavior` is in.

#### What I have done

In a subclass of `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, I inflate a view from XML and add it as a child of `CoordinatorLayout` (which is `BottomSheetDialogFragment`'s parent's parent):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setupBottomBar(getView());
}

private void setupBottomBar (View rootView) {
    CoordinatorLayout parentView = (CoordinatorLayout) ((FrameLayout)rootView.getParent()).getParent();
    parentView.addView(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_selection_bar, parentView, false), -1);
}
```

The code runs without error.
And when I use Layout Inspector to look at the View hierarchy, the view structure is also correct:

[image: Layout Inspector Screenshot]

You can also download the layout inspector result [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=34813213334752691638), and open it using your own Android Studio.

#### The problem

However, even though it is inserted as the last child of the `CoordinatorLayout`, it is still being blocked by the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.
When I slowly scroll the `BottomSheetDialogFragemnt` downwards (from collapsed state to hidden state), I can finally see the view that I want to inflate behind the fragment.

[image: View blocked]

Why is this happening?

### The answer

As @GoodDev pointed out correctly, it is because the root view (design_bottom_sheet) has been set a Z translation by `BottomSheetDialog`.
This provides an important information that - **not only sequence in a View hierarchy will determine its visibility, but also its Z translation.**

The best way is to get the Z value of `design_bottom_sheet` and set it to the bottom bar layout.

```
private void setupBottomBar (View rootView) {
    CoordinatorLayout parentView = (CoordinatorLayout) (rootView.getParent().getParent());
    View barView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_selection_bar, parentView, false);
    ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(barView, ViewCompat.getZ((View)rootView.getParent()));
    parentView.addView(barView, -1);
}
```

Comment: So what's the root view of your fragment?

Comment: It can be obtained by `getView()` inside the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. If you are asking what is the root element of my fragment's XML, well, it is a `FrameLayout`; but this is not related because this `FrameLayout` refers to the "design_bottom_sheet" in the View hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

Ok, now I see your requirement, try this one:

```
private void setupBottomBar (View rootView) {
    CoordinatorLayout parentView = (CoordinatorLayout) ((FrameLayout)rootView.getParent()).getParent();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_selection_bar, parentView, false);
    // using TranslationZ to put the view on top of bottom sheet layout
    view.setTranslationZ(100);
    parentView.addView(view, -1);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

OK, I check your layout and check the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` source code, found the reason:

In `BottomSheetDialogFragment` using `BottomSheetDialog` dialog, the method `setContentView` in [BottomSheetDialog](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog.java#69) using [`wrapInBottomSheet`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog.java#126) to put the content view in `R.id.design_bottom_sheet` layout. So you need override the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`'s `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` to fix your problem.

Or, change your `setupBottomBar` method to:

```
private void setupBottomBar (View rootView) {
    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)rootView.getParent();
    frame.addView(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_selection_bar, frame, false), -1);
}
```

and in your `item_selection_bar` layout file, change height and layout_gravity:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

---

[BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment.html) doc says: Modal bottom sheet. This is a version of DialogFragment that shows a bottom sheet using `BottomSheetDialog` instead of a floating dialog.

So the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is a `Dialog`, `Dialog` is a floating view, so will cover the Activity content when `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is showing.

Comment: But I am not inserting the view in Activity. I am inserting in the DialoigFragment.

Comment: Look the `wrapInBottomSheet` method source code,  you should add view in `R.id.design_bottom_sheet` FrameLayout. not the Dialog root layout.

Comment: This is the same as adding the view as part of  the XML I inflated in onCreateView, which cannot fulfill the requirement because I need it to stick at the bottom. I guess you may not know - the view you inflated in onCreateView will be partly hidden when the state of BottomSheetBehavior is in `COLLAPSED`. That's why I did such strange thing to inflate it on a higher level in hierarchy.

Comment: Ok, now I see your requirement, try this one:
    
    private void setupBottomBar (View rootView) {
        CoordinatorLayout parentView = (CoordinatorLayout) ((FrameLayout)rootView.getParent()).getParent();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_selection_bar, parentView, false);
        // using TranslationZ to put the view on top of bottom sheet layout
        view.setTranslationZ(100);
        parentView.addView(view, -1);
    }

Comment: Yes, your EDIT 2 is the correct answer! By the way, for it to work in pre-lollipop device, Use `ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(view, 100)` instead. And as @CoXier suggested, get the translaztionZ value from the bottomSheet is better than using `100`. Thanks!

Comment: I use `getZ()` instead of  `getTranslaztionZ ()`.

Answer (score 1):

@goodev has give a nice answer.

## Your problem

**View's `Z` position causes this problem.** Although the TextView is the last position you still can not see it.

[image]
[image]

## How to solve

You can set `design_sheet_bottom's Z` to TextView.

```
 private void setupBottomBar (View rootView) {
    CoordinatorLayout parentView = (CoordinatorLayout) ((FrameLayout)rootView.getParent()).getParent();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_selection_bar, parentView, false);
    view.setZ(((View)rootView.getParent()).getZ());
    parentView.addView(view, -1);
}
```

And I think above way is very boring, can you put your two view `RecyclerView` and `TextView` into a layout ? Then you can inflate theme together in `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: You have got it right. However, you still don't understand why putting those 2 views in a layout won't work lol. The `RecyclerView`, which is inside the `design_bottom_sheet`, can be collapsed or expanded by user. This is a fundamental feature of `BottomSheetDialog`. And unless the state of `BottomSheetBehavior` is in `EXPANDED`, the bottom part of the sheet will be hidden below the screen. That's why I cannot put the `TextView` in the same layout with `RecyclerView` because it will be hidden, but I need it to stick at the bottom.

Comment: Btw, +1 for getting Z value from rootView!